# How to Iterate over a list of strings in drl file in when clause

Tags: jboss, drools

This is my drl file. Person is a pojo object and has Name.

```
rule "AlertsCorrelation_5 : Do not group Disk Usage and Full GC together"
when
         $alertsRawList : List() ;
         $separateList : List() ;
         $nameObject : List() ;
         $listOfNames : List() ;
         $listOfNames.add("Test1");
         $listOfNames.add("Test2");
         System.out.println("listOfNames :\t"+$listOfNames);
         $matchedAlertList: List() from 
           collect(
                        Person(Name=="Test1"||Name=="Test2")  from $alertsRawList;

                  );
         for(Object name:$listOfNames){
           String s = (String)alertname;
          $nameObject.add(s);

         }


then      

          System.out.println($nameObject);
end
```

When using this drl file I am facing following error. I am not able to iterate over list of strings in when clause where as I am able to iterate over list in then clause. Please help me to figure out why it is going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure that's java?

Comment: The typical use of the LHS is to match certain pattern and to then delegate any action to the RHS. Couldn't you just move that `for` to your RHS?